# AMPScript FormatDate() culture codes list

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've searched the internet and even opened a ticket with Salesforce in search of culture codes that are compatible with the 4th sting in this function:

```
%%=FormatDate("2012-10-05 03:21:34.567890", "MMM DD, YYYY", "HH:MM:SS.MMM", "en-US")=%%
```

I could spend hours making guesses and testing, but before I go thought all that, I was hoping maybe someone in the community knows where I can find a list of popular countries and their respective codes that are supported in this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came across this lovely document.  If it has always been there, i don't know how I missed it before, but here you go if you came across this post:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=5

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is [this Microsoft library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee797784(CS.20).aspx)

Or you could reference [this resource from .basicdatepicker.com](http://www.basicdatepicker.com/samples/cultureinfo.aspx).

Sample Image of a snippet from .basicdatepicker.com:

[image]

Comment: thanks, Gortonington.  Do you know if ALL of these are compatible with AMPscript/SFMC?

Comment: I would say with confidence yes to the MSO ones, the ones on basicdatepicker.com I cannot say 100% though - but I would say more than likely yes.